# resolveInstanceMethod with unknown number of arguments

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

**Context:**

I have a dependency injection container - www.typhoonframework.org

It allows using the interface for defining components to resolve them at runtime - using resolveInstanceMethod and implentationWithBlock to trampoline the request to DI container.

Users have been asking for some parameters to be provided at runtime. For example:

```
[assembly dangerousEnemyWithWeapon:id<BigGun>]
```

. . where the enemy is assembled from collaborating classes in the DI container, but the gun is provided at runtime. . .

**The Question:**

Is it possible to use resolveInstanceMethod to define an implementation where the number of arguments is not known up front?

I would like to package up these arguments, and forward them on to another responder.

The arguments could be packed in order or added to a dictionary with the matching selector part as key.

Comment: Have you looked at `forwardingTargetForSelector:`?  It's slower than `resolveInstanceMethod:` but much faster than `forwardInvocation:`.  Perhaps it would meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rob. . I want to translate the selector and arguments to [container componentForKey:key withArguments:<a map or array>] . . Good to know about the performance characteristics of that method though - this is potentially important.

Comment: What is `key`?  Do you know the class of the object to which you want to forward the message?

Comment: Key is the unique ID of a component in the DI container. Yes, I know the class is TyphoonComponentFactory, but exposed via a TyphoonAssembly subclass' interface. . So invocations of method xyz on the TyphoonAssembly interface will result in [factory objectForKey:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd) args:<any runtime args>] . . here's the original impl: https://github.com/jasperblues/Typhoon/blob/master/Source/Factory/Block/TyphoonBlockComponentFactory.m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `+resolveInstanceMethod:` for that, but you can use traditional forwarding. `+resolveInstanceMethod:` just installs a new instance method on the class using the Objective-C runtime. You don't get to affect how it is called. It will be called just like any other method with the arguments in the registers and on the stack as the caller supplied them. You don't get an opportunity to package or marshal the arguments.

If you implement `-forwardInvocation:` and `-methodSignatureForSelector:`, then you get an `NSInvocation` object. That's already a packaging of the arguments (and return value). You can use that as it is or interrogate it to unpack the arguments and repack them how you want.

Comment: Thanks Ken. . I'm already using resolveInstance method for something else, but I think I can get away with converting that to use forwardInvocation.  .

Comment: `forwardInvocation:` is far, far slower than `resolveInstanceMethod:`.  Just FYI.

Comment: I got my original use case to work with forwardInvocation instead of resolveInstanceMethod. . I think this will work for me. . Performance potentially a problem, though.

Comment: Other than NSInvocation, the only way to package arbitrary parameters is to write assembly code. It's not pretty.